# C:about use a lseek system call by using an offset surpass the current seek_set

Tags: c, linux, unix, system-calls, seek

Code is from

```
char buf1[] = "abcdefghij";
char buf2[] = "ABCDEFGHIJ";

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;

    if((fd = creat("file.hole", 0777)) < 0)
        perror("creat error");

    if(write(fd, buf1, 10) != 10)
        perror("buf1 write error");
    if(lseek(fd, 04000, SEEK_SET) == -1)
        perror("lseek error");

    if(write(fd, buf2, 10) != 10)
        perror("buf2 write error");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

read file by

> od -c file.hole

and Output:

```
0000000   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000020  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
*
0004000   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
0004012
```

if i remove lseek , and creat file.nohole, the output will be

```
0000000   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   A   B   C   D   E   F
0000020   G   H   I   J
0000024
```

There are two problem make me confused.

```
> 1.At output1, why there are 30 * '\0' after j
> 2.output1: why file ends with 0004012 not 0004010
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.At output1, why there are 30 * '\0' after j

Not 30, but almost 04000. `od` truncated the output because it was huge and repetitive. Why are there zeroes? Because you told your program to insert them. `lseek()` padded the file.

> why file ends with 0004012 not 0004010

It doesn't - it's again `od` prints addresses in octal, not in hexadecimal (as you may have expected).

Comment: For the second part: I don't think that's the confusion. Probably more that `012 == 10 == 0x0A`.

Comment: @Mat Ah, so `hexdump` prints offsetts in octal?

Comment: `hexdump` outputs hex addresses by default, but `od` (which the OP is using) uses octal by default - that's visible from the first two lines - 16 bytes but line two is labeled 020.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot it, thank you for your answer,i don't know in od, * means repeated \0